# How to find out which column(s) violated which constraints (and checks) when calling SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Suppose I am building an ASP.NET Core web app using PostgreSQL as datastore (using Npgsql provider) and I have a Person entity model such as

```cs
[Index(nameof(EmailAddress), IsUnique = true)]
[Index(nameof(EmployeeNo), IsUnique = true)]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int EmployeeNo { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when user provides me these details by submitting a form and in my business logic I create a Person instance and save to the database using `_db.SaveChangesAsync()`

Now, suppose there is already a Person in DB with given EmailAddress or EmployeeNo. So `_db.SaveChangesAsync()`  will throw `DbUpdateException`.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I know which of the two - EmailAddress or EmployeeNo - caused this error. Either one of them or both of them might have caused it. So how do I know which one?
2. How to know the cause behind this error: Was it because of the unique index constraint? Or was it because of the `[Required]` attribute.
3. What kind of error handling techniques (using try-catch) should be used here?
4. What about error happened by integeroverflow, string length mismatch, etc.?
5. How about handling error caused by `MaxLength` attribute?

Thanks!

##### Include provider and version information

EF Core version: 5.0.8
Database provider: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.Postgres
Target framework:  .NET 5.0
Operating system: Windows
IDE: VS Code

Comment: 1.I'm afraid not, that based on the error message. You can only debug your code to figure out which property caused this exception. </br>    2.[Required] attribute will is used to make the property not null. Details see [this document](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/required-attribute-dataannotations-in-code-first.aspx).   3. I think try catch is ok.   4. debug?  5. modify the database column setting  or cut the length of your entering.

Comment: Did I misunderstand in some place?

Comment: I think what you need to do is adding validation for the data sending in before the data saved in the database. You can add the validate model in frontend or backend. E.g. if you use Razor pages as the view you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to add validation.

Comment: @TinyWang Yes you can add data validation for Maxlength or Required on the front end. But it is not possible for Unique constraint as you need to access database for that and that's one more trip to db. My question is after db throws DbUpdateException how can I know which column and constraint caused it?

Comment: @rickandmotry yes, and what's your requirement? Did you mean that you wanna a validation to check if the input data can pass all the validation of all the columns? If so, you also need to do a query to check if they are unique in the database before saving them.

Comment: @TinyWang I want to catch DbUpdateException and then show an error message to the user as "The email address you provided already exists."

Comment: Hmmm, and I think you have 2 ways to realize it. One way is as you said using try catch, after validating the data you can do without database, you insert the data and it will return exception and you can manage the return message in the `catch{}` module, the disadvantage is you can't tell the user if the email or number caused the exception. The second is start a query to check if the email and employ number is or not unique and then set response message or doing saving action.

Comment: if you met some error on how to realize that logic or some exception? Pls feel free to show us your issue

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1959, where the above questions have been answered.